# Remap USB device default productId from udev rule

Tags: udev, usb-device, lsusb

I have a device which is being assigned the productId of `1713` by modalias:

```
$ lsusb -s 001:008
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1e71:1713 NZXT NZXT USB Device

$ lsusb -t | grep "Dev 8"
    |__ Port 12: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M

$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-12\:1.0/uevent
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
DRIVER=usbhid
PRODUCT=1e71/1713/200
TYPE=0/0/0
INTERFACE=3/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v1E71p1713d0200dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in00
```

However, I would like to use a program (https://openrgb.org) which recognises this device [under the productId `2005`](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/blob/master/Controllers/NZXTHue2Controller/NZXTHue2ControllerDetect.cpp#L10)

Is there any way to create an udev rule to remap `1713` to `2005`?

I have already tried the below unfruitful methods:

1. `modprobe usbhid && echo "1e71 2005" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/new_id`
2. Adding `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-nzxt-usb.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", \
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTR{idVendor}=="1e71", \
ATTR{idProduct}="2005", \
RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -qba usbhid"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The productId is USB information and provided by the USB layer, you cannot change this through udev rules.

However, openrgb is open source, and [encourages](https://openrgb.org) you to add your own devices. So just [download the source](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB), modify it, compile it, and if it works, submit a patch.

---

Vendor and Product are part of the "USB Device Descriptor", which is part of the standard USB protocol. This can be only read from the device, and the kernel makes it available as read.

Have a look [here](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors) for the descriptor, and [here](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb6.shtml#SetupPacket) for the request that reads the descriptor.

Comment: Thanks, Dirkt. I will do that. By any chance, would you mind, expanding on how this information is locked by the device? It would be interesting to learn. Does it mean that every vendor has their own ID associated with the Kernel and each one of their registered products also inherits a specific Id? I ask because in this case, https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues/528, another user seemed to have the productId of 2005 for the same motherboard.

Comment: See answer for an explanation of the USB protocol (I can recommend reading the whole site). And yes, different product ids for the same motherboard can happen; the vendor of the device can specify the product id, and can do whatever he wants with it.

Comment: That's gold. Thanks so much. I will definitely read it through.